# Nullpointer Exception using ArrayList with ResultSet

Tags: java, iterator, arraylist, nullpointerexception, resultset

I have a function "getStudent()" that returns an ArrayList of strings and when i call this function in another class, i get a NullPointerException, i thought i had correctly initialized my List.

Here are the two functions and the line i get a NullPointerException is in bold.

```
 public ArrayList<String> getStudents(){

try
{
    System.out.println("gets here ");

    Statement newStat = this.conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    ResultSet res = newStat.executeQuery("SELECT FirstName FROM Students");

            String data = "";
    while (res.next()){

    studentList.add(res.getString("FirstName"));
    }

}
catch(SQLException e){
    System.err.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
}
 return studentList;
}
```

Function that calls 'getStudents()'

```
  public class CancelListener implements ActionListener{
    private  Main_Menu menu;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();;
    Iterator iterator = arrayList.iterator();


      public CancelListener(Main_Menu menu) {
      this.menu = menu;
    }

  @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("Cancel")){

    **arrayList = StudentModel.getStudents();**// NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION

    while(iterator.hasNext()){

       System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
    }
    this.menu.resetStudent();
    }

    }
 }
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `StudentModel` variable is probably null. The code you posted doesn't show how that variable is initialized so I can't tell you exactly what you're doing wrong, but when you reach the line marked it must be null.

You should check that you are initializing that variable correctly before you try to use it.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't initialize `StudentModel`. But I can't tell for sure since this part of the code doesn't appear here.

Comment: thank you. i had to initialize StudentModel and it worked right away

Answer (score 0):

getStudents() isn't static, and it looks like you're calling it as a static method (judging by the way you've capitalized StudentModel.)  So, as others have already said, you probably need to instantiate a StudentModel object, then call instance.getStudents().

Further, I don't see where you're creating an array instance.  getStudents() adds items to studentList, but we don't see how studentList is initialized.  This might also be the problem.  Frankly, given what you're doing, there's probably no reason to make studentList an instance variable.  So just declare the variable locally and allocate the array in the getStudents() method.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you think you initialized the list correctly, but this isn't what you are getting the exception on.   Also, you may have another problem.
You get an iterator for your list:
Iterator iterator = arrayList.iterator();
Then you assign a different object to that reference:
**arrayList = StudentModel.getStudents();**// NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION
Then you try to use the iterator:
while(iterator.hasNext()){

My understanding is that this shouldn't cause an exception, since you're not making changes to list the iterator refers.  But, you are almost certainly iterating through a different list that you think you are.  Is it possible you may be mis-interpreting an exception that is somehow caused here?

Comment: Your first comment about setting the iterator to arrayList.iterator() and then later setting it to a different list was not the problem. However, that did cause another problem for me and i removed the first instance (solved that problem). The exception was caused by me not initializing the StudentModel object as mentioned above. Thanks for the tip though